# Express server issues for index.html, bundle.js, serving index.html for every router (b/c of react-router) and more

Tags: express, react-router

I have this:

```
let dir = __dirname + "/dist"
app.use(express.static(dir));
```

I log out `dir` and see that the URL is indeed the same location I've compiled (via `webpack`) my `bundle.js`.  yet if (in `Postman`) I run a `GET` for `localhost:8080/dist/bundle.js` I get a `Cannot GET /dist/bundle.js` response.

Comment: Should be `/bundle.js` not `/dist/bundle.js`. The root is not included in the URL

Comment: sorry, this is after making a dozen changes to my server responses to things like returning the same index.html for every route, serving static assets, and also hitting my API routes.  its just so confusing that i'm beginning to miss obvious things.

Comment: I'm having to add `app.use((req, res) => res.sendFile('${__dirname}/index.html'))` back in now, to support my react-router's reload requirement.  but now, again, i'm being served `index.html` for `bundle.js`.  this was the problem that originally led me into the OP problem.

Comment: You can do `app.use('/dist', express.static(…))`.

Comment: i mean its not that my goal is to have to use `/dist` in my client url.  its just ambient confusion around express and the requirements to `a)` serve index.html for every route, `b)` to statically serve `dist/bundle.js` and `c)` to then hit my api routes without being ruined by the first two steps.